# FindFit; not a valid variable

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

I am trying to fit the function in model, however I get

> General::ivar: 5000.` is not a valid variable.

this error.

My code is that and

```
wavelength = 2.094;
zdata = {0.5, 1.6, 3, 4.6, 6.6, 8.2, 9.8, 12.1, 14.2, 16.6}*10^4;
W = {266.16, 257.385, 261.69, 290, 323.855, 365.07, 406.19, 455.33, 
   503.65, 560.17};
data = Thread[{zdata, W^2}]
model = w0^2 + Msquared^2*(wavelength/(Pi*w0))^2*(z - z0)^2
fit = FindFit[
  data, {model, {w0 > 0, 1 < Msquared, z0 > 0}}, {w0, Msquared, z0}, 
  z]
```

I think it is very trivial but couldn't manage to find the error. NonLinearModelFit doesn't resolve the issue.

The model equation is here [https://www.wikiwand.com/en/M_squared#:~:text=It%20is%20calculated%20from%20the,M2%20is%20exactly%20one.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/M_squared#:%7E:text=It%20is%20calculated%20from%20the,M2%20is%20exactly%20one.)

Comment: They are constants I am trying to find the equation is in here ; https://www.wikiwand.com/en/M_squared#:~:text=It%20is%20calculated%20from%20the,M2%20is%20exactly%20one.

Comment: You use "z" as data and as a variable. Use 2 different names.

Comment: As @DanielHuber mentioned, you need to make sure you are using distinct variables.

Comment: @DanielHuber thank you it solved my issue, can you answer once again so that I can choose it as answer

Comment: You probably need 2 more changes:  (1) Put in a starting value for `z0` such as `{z0, 1}` and (2) Add `MaxIterations -> 5000` to `FindFit`.  And I might be in the minority with this but I would always use `NonlinearModelFit` in place of `FindFit` as `FindFit` only gives parameter estimates and no regression diagnostics as `NonlinearModelFit` does.  (You're going to find that the estimate of `z0` is 0.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DanielHuber has mentioned the main issue but you'll also need to make some other changes:  (1) Set a reasonable starting value for `z0` and (2) Either increase the maximum number of iterations to 5000 (`MaxIterations -> 5000`) or replace `FindFit` with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Here is one approach:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, {w0 > 0, 1 < Msquared, z0 > 0}}, {w0, Msquared, {z0, 1}}, z];
nlm["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Parameter confidence interval table]

Is having a 95% confidence interval for $M^2$ being $(0.969,1.393)$ good enough for your objective?  If not, you need more data or data with less measurement error.

Looking at the fit and residuals is also helpful to decide on if the data matches the theoretical model.  One essentially hopes for no apparent patterns.

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[z], {z, Min[zdata], Max[zdata]}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"z", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(W\), \(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Data and fit]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Predicted response", "Fit residual"}]
```

[image: Predicted responses vs fit residuals]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{zdata, nlm["FitResiduals"]}], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"z", "Fit residual"}]
```

[image: Predictor vs fit residual]

The residual fits don't look great as you have groups of neighboring points all above the fit or below the fit but you'll need to be the judge about that.

The webpage you mention is inadequate because it completely ignores any estimation of precision let alone what level of precision might be needed and any possible lack-of-fit.

Answer (score 2):

Look at "z". You use it for storing data:

```
z = {0.5, 1.6, 3, 4.6, 6.6, 8.2, 9.8, 12.1, 14.2, 16.6}*10^4;
```

and you also use it as a variable:

```
model = w0^2 + Msquared^2*(wavelength/(Pi*w0))^2*(z - z0)^2
```

Use different names for different things.